# How do I read ICMP response from a port after sending an udp request without using raw socket

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp, icmp

I tried using SOCK_RAW, but it needs sudo permission.
Is there a way I could do it without sudo permission.

I followed this [link](http://www.matveev.se/cpp/portscaner.htm)

Comment: *"Is there a way I could do it without sudo permission."* - you need to have the right privileges which usually involves being root. It might be done if you have the appropriate capabilities (which you usually have not) - see http://squidarth.com/networking/systems/rc/2018/05/28/using-raw-sockets.html

Comment: You don't need raw sockets. Connect the socket to the target before sending. Any ICMP UNREACHABLE messages will then show up as error on subsequent sends or receives.

Answer (score 0):

You need root (or equivalent capabilities) to open a raw socket and read arbitrary network packets not associated with a connection you own. However, it's possible to get the useful information from the ICMP error response back through the UDP socket, as an error status interpreted by the kernel. I don't really understand how the interfaces for doing this work, but you can find some information starting from the [udp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html) man page.